# Help installing the Swampy python module?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, swampy

I need to install [swampy](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/) for the book [Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/).  I tried the documentation, but I can't figure it out.  I've been trying for a few days and can't continue the book until I install it.

I use Ubuntu.

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/swampy/issues/detail?id=1

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the indentation: it should be correct now. The author had some very strange indentation in his code.

I also moved two files, danger.gif and words.txt up one level to the main swampy folder. It seems to install for me. I didnt try to use it though, as I am not sure how, and I am not digging into that book. :P

I will host it temporarily in dropbox, please let me know when you have it, and if there is a problem still.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3735901/swampy-2.0.1.zip